# MPI_Irecv doesn't receive message in this easy code

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have this code for testing MPI_Irecv and MPI_Isend

```c
    if(rank==1){
        int cc;
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Status status;
        int flag;
        do{
            MPI_Irecv(&cc, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, allcomm, &request);
            //MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
            MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
            if (flag != 0) { 
                printf("recv : %d, slave : %d\n", cc, status.MPI_SOURCE);
            }
        } while(flag != 0);

    }
    if(rank==0){
        int cc=0;
        MPI_Request request;
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
            cc+=1;
            MPI_Isend(&cc, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, allcomm, &request);
        }
    }
```

If I execute this code, sometimes it prints cc from 1 to 9 and sometimes it prints nothing.

It makes sense, since the process 0 may be executed after process 1 finish.

However, if I let process 1 be a infinity loop like this:

```c
    if(rank==1){
        int cc;
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Status status;
        int flag;
        do{
            MPI_Irecv(&cc, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, allcomm, &request);
            //MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
            MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
            if (flag != 0) { 
                printf("recv : %d, slave : %d\n", cc, status.MPI_SOURCE);
            }
        } while(true);

    }
```

I think process 1 will print cc from 1 to 9 every time, but it won't.

If I insert MPI_Wait() in process 1, it seems process 1 will print cc from 1 to 9 every time. But it will also wait forever if there is nothing sent by other process and I want non-blocking communication actually.

Reply to comments:

1.About version:
mpiexec --version
mpiexec (OpenRTE) 2.1.1

2.I don't get the point what 'MPI progress thread' means.

Actually I want each process can communicate with each other without blocking and get the information in the buffer each time when receive.

3.executable code following

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    MPI_Comm allcomm;
    int i;
    int size, rank, irank;
    int tablesize, localtablesize;
    int *table,*table2;

    allcomm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(allcomm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(allcomm, &rank);

    if(rank==1){
        int cc;
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Status status;
        int flag;
        do{
            MPI_Irecv(&cc, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, allcomm, &request);
            //MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
            MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
            if (flag != 0) { 
                printf("recv : %d, slave : %d\n", cc, status.MPI_SOURCE);
            }
        } //while(flag!=0);
        while(true);

    }
    if(rank==0){
        int cc=0;
        MPI_Request request;
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
            cc+=1;
            MPI_Isend(&cc, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, allcomm, &request);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: It seems you are expecting a MPI progress thread. Unfortunately, not all MPI implementations provide that (on every interconnect). Which MPI library (vendor+version) are you using ? can you also edit your question with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: you should try the lastest Open MPI (4.0.1). if you `MPI_Isend()`, then nothing might happen until an other MPI subroutine such as `MPI_Wait()` or `MPI_Test()` is invoked ... unless the MPI library has a progress thread. If you post a [MCVE], then I will tell you for sure if the (lack of) progress thread is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: see my answer, MPI progress thread is out of the picture here.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is incorrect.

For example, if rank `1` is faster than rank `0`, the first `MPI_Test()` will not match any message and then go straight to `MPI_Finalize()`

Bottom line, this program might print between 0 and 10 lines.
This program will only print 10 lines if rank `1` is somehow lagging behind rank `0`, but since both ranks are not synchronized, this is quite unlikely to happen.

Comment: I've mentioned it, "It makes sense, since the process 0 may be executed after process 1 finish." However, if I let process 1 be a infinity loop with `while(true)`, I think process 1 will print cc from 1 to 9 every time, but it won't.

Comment: If rank `1` is lagging, it will end up issuing more than 10 `MPI_Irecv()`, but only the first 10 has the potential of being matched, that is why your program might hang.

Comment: but the first 10 don’t output sometimes, I want to know why. In other word, is there any solution can never miss the first 10? It seems this code will miss the first 10 sometimes.

Comment: if rank `1` is late, `MPI_Test()` will not match a message, and since you simply lose the request, you have no way to match the message when it arrives.

Comment: I see. So it is impossible to use `Irecv` and `Isend` to realize this function? I'm trying to use `Bsend`, but it seems I must use blocking 'Recv' to receive the message in the buffer...

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to achieve so I can hardly advise. You might want to post 10 `MPI_Irecv()` with an array of `MPI_Request` and use `MPI_Testany()` or friends.